# App Pool Recycling and workflows

Tags: iis, workflow-foundation-4, application-pool

In this scenario, WF 4 WCF workflow service (xamlx's) hosted in IIS, how does one accomodate the fact that the app pool may be recycled at any time (config edit, memory pressure, etc.) and one or more WCF initiated workflow(s) may still be executing when the app pool is being torn down and restarted.   The concern is that a workflow may be executing it's activities and the IIS host tear down may prevent that thread (or threads if async activities used) from completing and leave the workflow in an unstable state.   We could use transaction scope or some other construct for this but not sure of the overall behavior in order to best plan on how to accomodate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS has a feature called Overlapped Recycle that is enabled by default resulting in the previous AppPool being granted some time before it is completely destroyed. I believe this feature was first introduces in IIS 7.5. You should be able to find it under Application Pools/Advanced Settings/Recycling I don't recall the exact amount of time but providing you are not doing extensive computation you should be fine.